# Pandas : select columns that ends with another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dirty dataset where two columnns that I need to match are not properly formatted :

- "id" is a string often made of digits, that potentially starts with zero
- "parent_id" represents the id of the parent of the row, but it has been formatted to an int, and so the starting zeros are gone.

I want to find for which rows "id" is the same as "parent_id".  However, I cannot manage to match it like this :

```
df["is_the_same"] = (df["id"]==df["parent_id"])
```

cause some of them would not match  (for example, the id "01004" has "1004" as parent_id, and would not match in this case)

How can I select columns that have "id" equal to "parent_id" once potential zeroes have been removed ?

I also tried :

```
df["is_the_same"] = df["id"].str.endswith(df["parent_id"])
```

But it seems .str.endswith  only work with constant strings (another column)

Comment: Does this help? `int('01004') == int('1004')` returns `True`

Comment: most (but not all) of the ids are composed only of digits, so turning them into int will not work for the general case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `endswith`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['01004','1004','54620'], 'parent_id':['1004','203','20']})

df["is_the_same"] = [x.endswith(y) for x, y in df[["id","parent_id"]].values]
#alternative
#df["is_the_same"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["id"].endswith(x["parent_id"]), axis=1)
print (df)
      id parent_id  is_the_same
0  01004      1004         True
1   1004       203        False
2  54620        20         True
```

If difference only leading zeros and numbers compare converted values to integers:

```
df["is_the_same"] = df["id"].astype(int) == df["parent_id"].astype(int)
print (df)
      id parent_id  is_the_same
0  01004      1004         True
1   1004       203        False
2  54620        20        False
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Series.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html), you can strip off leading zeros from `id` column and then match it with `parent_id` column, like this:

```
df["id"].str.lstrip('0') == df["parent_id"]
```

Assume this to be `df`:

```
In [68]: df 
Out[68]: 
      id parent_id
0  01004      1004
1   1004      1004
2    546       100

In [70]: df["is_the_same"] = df["id"].str.lstrip('0') == df["parent_id"]        
In [71]: df    
Out[71]: 
      id parent_id  is_the_same
0  01004      1004         True
1   1004      1004         True
2    546       100        False
```